# Extracting information from Ubuntu man pages

Tags: command-line, manpage

I am trying mine data from ubuntu manpages and generate statistics such as how many command manpages have examples section or how to use a command combining different options and much more, automatically to feed to an automation program. I thought of couple of approaches but they have their own limitations associated with them.

1. Use regex to extract information on manpages text documents. But it seems to get messy for this task as the format and organization of different sections are not consistent among all the manpages. Inconsistency in the manpages format seems to be an established problem.
2. Use HTML/XML parser on html/xml format of manpages as it gives more structure over text format. Sections can be identified with heading tags and options organized as list elements in html format. But the problem here is I didn't find any html format downloadable collection of manpages. The closest I was able to find is html format of Linux distribution, which will miss certain commands of Ubuntu world. I tried converting manpages to html format through command line using man2html software but it doesn't structure it nicely. The generated html format combines everything under one main html tag set.

Any suggestions on how to approach this problem? Could somebody give a pointer to code implementations of already done work in this space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `catman`:

```
trusty (8) catman.8.gz
Provided by: man-db_2.6.7.1-1_i386 

NAME
       catman - create or update the pre-formatted manual pages

SYNOPSIS
       catman [-d?V] [-M path] [-C file] [section] ...

DESCRIPTION
       catman  is  used  to  create  an up to date set of pre-formatted manual
       pages known as cat pages.  Cat  pages  are  generally  much  faster  to
       display  than  the  original  manual  pages,  but require extra storage
       space.  The decision  to  support  cat  pages  is  that  of  the  local
       administrator, who must provide suitable directories to contain them.
```

to simplify the files, then it's a SMOP. I suggest that a Perl script should be able to extract the data you want. One can easily detect the command name (and use that to find actual examples), find the `EXAMPLES` section (if it exists), count the number of times the letter "`e`" is used, ... with Perl.